# NodeJs MulterS3 Uploading images stopped working

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, multer

I have been working with NodeJs, Multer, Multer-S3 to upload an image in a multipart from android studio to AWS S3.

I had the code working and I saw the images being stored in the storage. However I come back to my code a few hours later and there is an error being sent now when I try to upload an image (and even the same images as before, before and after wiping the storage clean so no dupes)

```
     Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 169.254.169.254:80
     at Object._errNoException(util.js:1024:11)
     at _exceptionWithHostPort(util.js:1046:20)
     at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1182:14)    
     at=info method=POST path="/item/postimage"
     host=dana-fyp-restaurant-app.herokuapp.com
     request_id=c8091a3c-ec82-44e6-9787-c19da95d244b fwd="81.108.210.57"
     dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=1080ms status=500 bytes=404
     protocol=https
```

I am so confused why this was working and with no changes to the code, it stops working.

Can anyone please point me in the right direction. Thanks

Comment: can you add some of the codes you used in the post to enable use understand you clearly?